# Name error python

Tags: python-2.7

I am fairly new to python and I keep getting this error:

> "NameError: name 'prompt' is not defined"

Heres the code that I am trying to run:

```
def accountLogin(prompt):
    while true:
        if(os.path.exists("info.csv")):
            return
        else:
            print "Please enter username and password"

        if len(username) < 0:
            print "please enter username"
        elif len(username) > 0: 
            println "please enter password"     
            return
        if password = false:
            print "please enter password"
        elif password = true:
            return "info.csv"
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong, where to start... `println` is not correct, `==` to compare, not `=` - that's assign...

Comment: How are you calling accountLogin?

Comment: @Luke.py accountLogin(raw_input);
        info.csv

Comment: dont pass raw_input... pass the variable associated with raw_input

Comment: Yes it should and I defined it as a string in my new code so it's returning an error saying the string is not callable

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want, and I am newbie like you, any way hope this code will help you, please vote to my answer.

```
def get_formatted_name(username, password):
    """Return a all info, neatly formatted."""
    all_info = username + ' ' + password
    return all_info.title()

while True:
    print("\nPlease tell me your username:")
    print("(enter 'q' at any time to quit)")

    username = raw_input("Username: ")
    if username == 'q':
        break
    password = raw_input("Password: ")
    if password == 'q':
        break

formatted_name = get_formatted_name(username, password)
print("\nYour account information is, " + formatted_name + "!")
```

You can read about while loop for more info.

Give me your vote, I need it.
Thanks

Comment: how would you call that

Answer (score 0):

```
def accountLogin(username,password):
        if len(username) == 0:
                username = str(raw_input("please enter username: ")).translate(None, "'").translate(None, '"')
                return(username,password)
        if len(password) == 0:
                password = str(getpass.getpass("please enter password: ")).translate(None, "'").translate(None, '"')
                return(username,password)
        else:
                return(username,password)
loginUsername,loginPassword = accountLogin(loginUsername,loginPassword)
```